# Как получить нужную часть через регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Использую preg_match_all.

Есть страница, с которой нужно спарсить часть кода. 
Сам код выглядит примерно так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var elements = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5};
</script>
```

Вот мне и нужно получить только json-часть, то есть `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`

Если использую

```
if (preg_match_all('#var wallpapers = (.*?);#si',$image_page,$matchimages,PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
```

Получаю `var elements = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте содержимое `$matchimages[0][1]`, там должна быть нужная строка.

Либо попробуйте что-то вроде этого:

```
preg_match_all('/{[^}]*}/', $image_page, $matchimages);
```

Comment: Ну это я знаю, а никак не получится, чтобы изначально в массиве было только значение?

Comment: Вам тогда надо задать в шаблоне выражения правило, как выбрать только искомое. Добавил пример в ответ.